# How to get a minion to run at a certain time rather than at an interval

Tags: commerce-engine

Lets say I want my minion to run once every hour then I config this in the Environment file.

```
  {
    "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Core.MinionPolicy, Sitecore.Commerce.Core",
    "WakeupInterval": "01:00:00",
    "ListToWatch": "ReleasedOrders",
    "FullyQualifiedName": "Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Orders.ReleasedOrdersMinion, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Orders",
    "ItemsPerBatch": 10,
    "SleepBetweenBatches": 500
  },
```

But what if I want more control over when it actually runs? Like if I want it to run exactly every quarter past every hour. How do I configure that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore Minions are like agents/jobs from Sitecore. You can not syncronize them OOTB a give time.

@Aksay Sura explained in a blogpost how to run minions at a specific time.

First of all you need to install Sitecore Cron : https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecron

The source code for sitecore can be find at: https://github.com/akshaysura/Sitecron

He created a nice video where is explaind how to configure it: https://youtu.be/tCnooSlifsk

Please have a look on his blogpost : https://www.konabos.com/blog/run-sitecore-commerce-xc-9-minion-using-sitecore-precision-scheduling-with-sitecron-in-powerful-ways